# Convolutions in log-scale axis

Tags: fft, convolution

Suppose I have two signals $f[x]$ and $g[x]$ defined over a grid of $2N+1$ points ${x}_{i}$, so that the difference $|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|$ between points is logarithmically spaced with base 10. Thus, the grid ${x}_{i}$ is logarithmically spaced.

I would like to know if there is a method to compute the convolution integral $(f*g)(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)g(y-x)\,\mathrm dx$ of the two signals by means of a FFT algorithm.

Since the ${x}_{i}$ are not linearly spaced, the FFT is not directly applicable; however, in a variable $z=\log_{10}(x)$, both functions are defined over equidistant samples; therefore the question is on how to represent the convolution integral in $z$, to later apply the FFT algorithm, but with $f[z],g[z]$, that is, the original signal defined on the $z$ grid, which is linearly spaced.

Is there an easy way to do this? The functions $f,g$ do not have an analytical description, they are just numerically defined at the discrete points of the grid.

**Extended explanation:** The grid does not in fact need to be with base 10 logarithmic separation, but any other log scale. The grid is defined by $X=\{x_{i=1,...,2N+1}\}$ points. For each point $x_{i}$, we have $f[x_{i}],g[x_{i}]$ as our signals, so $X$ defines the support of these functions. They don't have an analytic closed form, the only known fact is that at the edges they decay to zero, so $f[x_{1}]=f[x_{2N+1}]=0$.

If the grid points are equally spaced, so that $\Delta x_{i}=\Delta x$ for any $i$, then the convolution integral can be approximated by a discrete sum:
\begin{eqnarray}
(f*g)(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)g(y-x) dx \approx \Delta x  \sum_{i}f[x_{i}]g[x_{i}-y_{j}] =(f*g)[y_{j}]
\end{eqnarray}
with a target grid $Y\equiv X$, so the data points $\{y_{j=1,...,2N+1}\}$ are exactly those of $\{x_{i}\}$ ($y_{1}=x_{1}$, $y_{2}=x_{2}$,...,$y_{2N+1}=x_{2N+1}$). That means that the resulting function from the convolution is exactly defined in the same domain.

Now since the $f,g$ signals are defined over equally spaced samples, one can use the FFT algorithm to compute the convolution integral, by just using the discrete Fourier transform.

However, if $\Delta x_{i}$ is not constant, the FFT algorithm can't be applied, and the integral needs to be evaluated by other means. If the number of grid points is large, an $O(N^{2})$ operation becomes much more expensive than the $O(N\log N)$ of the FFT; therefore I am just looking for methods to efficiently evaluate the discrete convolution, as stated above. I started by using a non-uniform discrete Fourier transform (NUDFT):

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform#:%7E:text=In%20applied%20mathematics%2C%20the%20nonuniform%20discrete%20Fourier%20transform,It%20is%20a%20generalization%20of%20the%20shifted%20DFT.)

but I don't know if this really leads somewhere, and how that relates to directly compute the discrete sum.

Comment: what properties would the convolution you want to implement have? These functions *have* to have an analytical description, otherwise what you  do in the integral is  zero, always, and your question falters... From your original notation, I'm almost certain you are a physicist, so what *are* $f$ and $g$? What is the output's time grid you wand to have?

Comment: It's really confusing that you try to apply an integral to a product of two sequences – can you write down as formula what you *want* that to compute? Because you'd otherwise will have to define $\mathrm dx$ to be an interesting measure and I'm almost certain that if we go there, we will all learn a lot, but probably not answer your question.

Comment: Please find the edited question. The true nature of $f,g$ is not of relevance here, they are just discretized versions of two functions, two signals from which we only have data points at $x_{i}$. The integral is just the definition of a convolution integral between two functions, which can be discretized accordingly.

Comment: How about just resampling the data uniformly? Do you have time/memory constraints that don’t allow you to do this?

Comment: Yes that is precisely the problem, a uniform sampling would require many grid points due to the large scales covered by the grid, and the operation needs to be repeated many times, so in terms of performance while being the easiest, is not really efficient. Moreover, the data in f,g may contain peaks in values of $x$ close to zero, yet these are relevant when convolving.

Answer (score 1):

Worth looking into the [log Fourier transform](https://homepages.dias.ie/%7Eajones/publications/28.pdf) (and [FFTLog](https://jila.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/FFTLog/)), which I know nothing about except that its abstract reads exactly like what you seek:

> We  present an  exact and analytical expression for the Fourier transform of a function  that has been  sampled  logarithmically

Note, any such method necessarily imposes a *prior*. That is, convolution demands uniformity, i.e. knowledge of samples we don't possess, thus any counter result necessarily *interpolates* information. This is fine for natural signals, however, as they often possess structure and regularity to be exploited - the pub reads,

> For the  example  chosen,  we  are  able  to  obtain
> results  that agree  with  those from  an  FFT to  within  0.5  per cent

which is excellent.

Alternatively one can attain a piecewise approximation, patching the sample space over different slopes (sampling rates), which makes the output multirate. Or, interpolate explicitly (NNs, etc).